# How can i iterate trough a S4 object in R?

Tags: r, r-s4

I've created a class that holds pictures. To the class I have created two objects (two pictures). I want to have a loop that prints all pictures.

````
```{r echo=FALSE, comment=""}
# Generate class
setClass("Picture", slots=list(id="numeric", path="character"))

# Add first picture
full_file_path <- "testphoto.JPG"
pic_obj <- new("Picture", id=1, path=full_file_path)

# Add second picture
full_file_path <- "parrot.jpeg"
pic_obj <- new("Picture", id=2, path=full_file_path)

# Loop trough pictures (how? for? foreach? while?)
cat("ID=", pic_obj@id, "\n")
cat("Path=", pic_obj@path, "\n")
```
````

This prints:

```
ID= 2 
Path= parrot.jpeg
```

However I want this:

```
ID= 1 
Path= testphoto.JPG
ID= 2 
Path= parrot.jpeg
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are creating and overwriting the same object. For your problem you should either 1) have an object, that you can extend (such as `list`) or 2) create a list of objects that you can then iterate through.

Comment: How can I do this Oliver?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the two lines

```
pic_obj <- new("Picture", id=1, path=full_file_path)
```

and

```
pic_obj <- new("Picture", id=2, path=full_file_path)
```

create an object called `pic_obj` and then overwrite it, so the first one is lost. Instead, try either

```
pic_obj_1 <- new("Picture", id=1, path=full_file_path)
pic_obj_2 <- new("Picture", id=2, path=full_file_path)
```

or

```
pic_obj <- new("Picture", id=1:2, path=c(full_file_path_1,full_file_path_2))
```

if you do the second option, you need to make sure any methods (functions) you write for the `picture` class work with vector arguments.